# Error using pyenchant: enchant_dict_check: assertion `g_utf8_validate(word, len, NULL)' failed

Tags: python, dictionary, spell-checking, pyenchant

I'm trying to check a list of tags against the english dictionary. I'm using pyenchant and I keep getting error.    It seems to have an error after it reads a "?".  I attempted to take out all punctuation by using the string library and the following code:

```
for punc in string.punctuation:
    title = title.replace(punc,'')
```

but some how this char which appears to look like a ? is throwing off the dictionary.

Code snippet:

```
if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
    print word, "=", d.check(word) 
    if d.check(word):       
        tags.append(word.lower())
```

Response:

```
Learning = True
Lens = True
Children = True
Pumkincom = False
Pumkin = False

** (process:49042): CRITICAL **: enchant_dict_check: assertion `g_utf8_validate(word, len, NULL)' failed
     ? =
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and pyenchant-1.6.5-py2.7

EDIT: I think I solved this problem by checking to see if len(word)==1 but I would like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this problem before, but it was due to non English letters existing in the text
I advice you to make sure that word contains only English letters

Comment: I doubt if it is a non-english chrs which r creating problem. Instead I check dictionary.check('non-english') for non-english chrs it return False. I think this problem is related to encoding. String which is passed to dictionary.check() is not valid UTF-8 unicode string.